# what does ? mean inside a printf function in c

Tags: c, printf

I am learining about how to use sqlite3 on c and was lookinbg at this code:

```
static int callback(void *data, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName){
   int i;
   fprintf(stderr, "%s: ", (const char*)data);
   
   for(i = 0; i<argc; i++){
      printf("%s = %s\n", azColName[i], argv[i] ? argv[i] : "NULL");
   }
   
   printf("\n");
   return 0;
}
```

I was wondering what does ?, :, %s = %s mean in printf

```
printf("%s = %s\n", azColName[i], argv[i] ? argv[i] : "NULL");
```

I'm new to c and I'm still getting familiar to the syntax and the quirks of this language. Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: It's the ternary operator. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_other

Comment: This *question* has nothing to do with `sqlite`.

Comment: Gogo: Did I answer your question fully or do you want me to clarify anything futher?

Answer (score 3):

- `"%s = %s\n"`
  The first argument to [`printf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) is the format string which contains the text to print mixed with conversion specifiers. The conversion specifiers start with `%` and `%s` means *"replace this conversion specifier with a string"*. For every conversion specifier, `printf` expects that you've also supplied an argument matching that conversion specifier. In your case, you have two `%s` so there should be two `(const) char*` arguments after the first argument - which you also have.
- `azColName[i]`
  This supplies the *`i`:th* `char*` in `azColName` to `printf`
- `argv[i] ? argv[i] : "NULL"`
  This uses the [conditional operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_other#Conditional_operator) `? :` in order to supply the second string that `printf` expects (after the format string). It's built like this:

  ```
  condition ? expression-true : expression-false
  ```

  In your case it means, if `argv[i]` evaluates to `true` (that is, it's not a `NULL` pointer), the result of the expression will be `argv[i]`, otherwise it will be `"NULL"`. Both *expression-true* and *expression-false* are `char*` (in the case of `"NULL"`, it *decays* into a `char*`) and will therefore make `printf` happy.